# Retrieving current capslock state in Java

Tags: java

Using the following code:

```
Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getLockingKeyState(KeyEvent.VK_CAPS_LOCK)
```

Unfortunately, only returns false.

As per docs, this should work: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Toolkit.html#getLockingKeyState-int-

Runnable example:

```
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;


public class Foo {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1);

        executorService.execute(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                while(true) {
                    try{ Thread.sleep(250); }catch(Exception ignored) { }
                    System.out.println("Capslock state: " + Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getLockingKeyState(KeyEvent.VK_CAPS_LOCK));
                }
            }
        });

        executorService.shutdown();
    }

}
```

**Should add that I'm using Java SE 1.8 on Windows and that my Caplock key works fine**

Screenshot of console output:

[image]

Comment: There's [a bug report](http://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=4414164) on this issue that explains that on Windows, when an application has a frame with focus, this method will work; otherwise it will only return whatever the value was at program execution.

Comment: @Vulcan, this is incorrect in this case- Because it's returning false regardless of initial state. This also doesn't answer the question, as (isPressed) from JNA KeyUtils is not a solution for checking a locked keystate.

Answer (score 2):

Your code works fine for me. I just cut pasted your code, compiled it, ran it, and hit caps lock while it was running. Here was the output:

```
$ javac Foo.java
$ java Foo
Capslock state: false
Capslock state: false
Capslock state: false
Capslock state: false
Capslock state: true
Capslock state: true
Capslock state: true
Capslock state: true
Capslock state: true
Capslock state: true
Capslock state: true
Capslock state: true
Capslock state: false
Capslock state: false
Capslock state: false
^C
```

I'm using java 8, like you.

```
$ java -version
java version "1.8.0_25"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_25-b17)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.25-b02, mixed mode)
```

Is your caps lock key working?

Comment: `java -version
java version "1.8.0_11"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_11-b12)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.11-b03, mixed mode)`

And my caps lock key works fine, for me the value always returns false.

Comment: Screenshotted results for formatting: http://gyazo.com/a48e29dd4ab1f98e4e76e94e791bd684

Comment: I don't have that exact version of java on my system by I tried with the slightly older `jdk1.8.0_05` thats on my system and it worked as well.

Comment: @Christian.tucker Have you tried any other versions of java?

Comment: Are you running this from the command line or from an IDE?

Comment: @Asaph, I tried using both;

Comment: @Vulcan - No, but considering I'm writing this for an OpenGL game, a solution that works for most versions would definitely be preferred. This method dates back for quite awhile.

Comment: @Christian.tucker Of course, but that information could be used to help determine whether the issue lies in your Java version or something larger like your OS.

Comment: @Christian.tucker does the running app have focus when you're toggling caps lock?

Comment: Ok, so I see by your screenshot that you're running windows. That may be significant here. My tests were done on OS X.

Comment: @Asaph, I'm looking for a cross-platform solution.

Comment: Neither works for me `java version "1.8.0_20"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_20-b26)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.20-b23, mixed mode)` on  `Windows 7`I always get: `Capslock state: false`

Comment: I just tested it on Windows 8 with Java 1.8.0 and also notice that `false` is constantly printed regardless of actual key state.

Comment: If I start with caps lock on, then always get `true`. I notice that it correctly reads the first time but never updates during program exectution.

Answer (score 0):

Your code works fine on java 1.7.0_25 and 6. Just copy pasted it and ran, using netbeans.

Here is the result

```
Capslock state: true
Capslock state: true
Capslock state: true
Capslock state: true
Capslock state: true
Capslock state: true
Capslock state: true
Capslock state: true
pslock state: true
Capslock state: true
```

It should work on java 8 have you tried using IDE ?

I use windows 7.

Comment: I use eclipse; However ran it in CMD just to double check.

Comment: have you tried any other Key besides Capslock ? Just for testing